# Can women befriend LGBTQ men?

Tags: homosexuality

Salam,
My question is, is it allowed for a woman to befriend a gay man? I could find no answer, i'd love you to help me out and cit some sources.

Thanks

Comment: LGBTQ men don't exist, L=lesbian, G= gay ...

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of their sexuality, they are still men despite their attraction inclined to the same sex/gender. So the answer would be no.

Comment: Could you please cite a source brother/sister?

Comment: @Usrneym source of what? There’s hadiths where the Prophet (saws) warned brothers to not touch women and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Hadith and common fiqh only knows men and women. No difference is made between Eunuchs and men in general; even people born with two sexes tend to be gendered, see [here](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askmufti/81691/view-on-transgender/).

For the role and the rules in society, no difference is made between heterosexual men and gays.